# DataGridViewComboColumn Fill Data from database

Tags: c#

I am using below code to load data in combocolumn of datagridview but first description column I dont want please let me know how i can remove the first description column from datagridview

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    dataGridView1.DataSource = loadData();

    fillCombo();

}

private void fillCombo()
{

    DataGridViewColumnCollection columns = dataGridView1.Columns;
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Text = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

    Text.HeaderText = "ITEM";
    Text.Name = "ITEM";
    columns.Add(Text);

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    combo.HeaderText = "LOCATION";
    combo.Name = "combo";
    combo.DisplayMember = "LOCATION";
    combo.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
    ArrayList row = new ArrayList();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row.Add(dr["LOCATION"].ToString());

    }

    combo.Items.AddRange(row.ToArray());

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);
}

private DataTable loadData()
{

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    string sql = "Select * From Table1";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    return dt;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good practice to select * in cases like this, it makes it much easier for schema changes to break your application. My best suggestion would be to select Item and Location instead of *.  This means only Item and Location will show up in your grid.

Answer (score 0):

> Method1

DataGridTableStyle ts = new DataGridTableStyle();

```
private void deleteColumn()  
{  

   ts.MappingName = dataGrid1.DataMember;  


   dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(ts);  


   dataGrid1.TableStyles[0].GridColumnStyles.RemoveAt(0);  
}
```

> Method2

```
gridview.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;
```